# What will be the minimum value of this trigonometric function?

Tags: trigonometry

$$5\sin^2x - 12\sin x\cos x + 10\cos^2x$$
My doubt is that as this can be written as $(2\sin x - 3\cos x)^2 + 1$ and minimum value of $2\sin x -3 \cos x$ is $-13$, so will the minimum value be $14$, same  as maximum value?

Comment: do you mean maximum of $(2\sin x -3 \cos x)^2$ is 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**
you are minimizing $f(x) = g(x)^2 + 1$ and the minimum of $f$ will occur in the same place as the minimum of $g^2$. Clearly $g(x)^2 \ge 0$ so if you can set $g(x)=0$ you will get the minimum you seek.